# Can't notify/tag a specific person

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies

In this [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/32859/14341), suddenly I can't notify Ben Bitdiddle, typing "@B" won't show the autocomplete box. I have tried write "@Ben Bitdiddle" manual but after I enter, this notify words disappear (you can see yourself in this [latest comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32855/should-i-start-my-cv-by-telling-about-myself#comment73902_32859). Notify other people in other comment boxes on that same question still function. Refresh the page won't solve the problem. I use the latest Firefox version in Windoes 8.1.

Comment: The author of a post is notified of **all** comments on their post. As such, no explicit @name is needed and the autocompleter won't list their name for you. This is by design.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read the blog in that question and can't see it answers my question.

Comment: Hrm, I meant to dupe to [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) instead. The answer there covers everything you need to know.

Comment: Why does the system allow him to notify me either? If I do not need to notify him, it's reasonable for him to not need notify me as well.

Comment: For the most part, I *want* to be notified of comments on my posts. Usually they involve my answer or question; depending on where the discussion is going I may want to adjust my post.

Comment: There is only me to notify

Answer (score 1):

This user is the one who posted this answer, so you won't see autocomplete for his name (and you actually don't need to use @replies to notify him; he'll be notified anyway).

Moreover, if you type his whole name, it will be removed once your comment is submitted.

Comment: But I can notify him in the previous comments

Comment: @Ooker You can, always. Just his name will be removed from your comment. The user who posted the answer is always notified about comments on his posts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are the only other person who has commented on his answer and he is the one that posted the answer, the @-mention at the beginning is not needed. It is clear from context that you are talking to Ben because he is the owner and the only other person talking.

Since the owner of a post is *always* notified of new comments anyways, it is safe for the system to drop the username at the beginning. The conversation is not affected in any way.

Comment: so if Ben doesn't always notify me, can I still notify him?

Comment: Ben does not need your name there, either. Since you are the only person who commented, you will be notified of all his comments. The system assumes he is replying to you because there is no one else to reply to.

Comment: Why doesn't the system allow him to notify me either?